# Облачное хранилище Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Пишу диплом на Laravel, тема облачное хранилище, вот как оно должно работать на словах:

> После регистрации, пользователь попадает в личный кабинет, где он
> может создать папку и дать этой папке своё имя, и внутри этой папки он
> может загружать файлы.

Как сделать так, чтобы пользователь создавал
папку, и под эту папку создавалась отдельная таблица в БД дабы в этой таблице хранились файлы которые пользователь загружал в неё

Comment: В таблице файлы не стоит хранить, создаётся папка и в неё загружаются файлы... В таблицу (условно, uploads) можно записывать информацию о файле + путь до файла

Comment: И не надо создавать таблицу для каждого пользователя. Таблица должна быть одна, а в качестве одного из полей в ней - идентификатор пользователя, который загрузил файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это ужасная практика, так делать никогда не стоит.
Вместо этого используйте следующую архитектуру БД:

Таблица Folders:
`name, user_id`

Таблица Files: `path, folder_id`

Поля для БД я предоставил минимальные, которые вам точно нужны. Но возможно, вам понадобиться сохранять еще какую-то информацию (например, имя файла). Так-же я написал поле id, но оно необходимо само собой (так-же, как и временные метки, такие как created_at и updated_at). В миграции ларавель они уже по умолчанию имеются, просто не удаляйте их.

Теперь поговорим о том, как это использовать в Laravel:

Создайте модели с миграцией, командой:
`php artisan make:model -m`

Это создаст модель вместе с миграцией. В миграциях создайте те поля, о которых я сказал вам выше. Т.е. в итоге у вас будут две модели:

```
Folder - связана с таблицей Folders
File - связана с таблицей Files
```

После создания моделей и миграций, необходимо установить связи:

```
В модели Folder создайте связь один ко многим - hasMany с моделью File
В модели File создайте связь один к одному - belongsTo с моделью Folder
```

Так-же, вам нужно будет установить связь пользователя с папкой.
Логика будет следующая: От юзера вы подгружаете связь с папками, а от папки вы подгружаете связь с файлами, после этого вы сможете их без проблем выводить.